# Inno Setup Wizard Page onscreen placement (off-centre position)

Tags: inno-setup

I would like to specify that the Wizard Pages do not open in the middle of the screen by default i.e. to position them slightly off-centre using x,y coordinates (or a similar offset). This is because I call another program that also opens in the middle of the screen, obscuring the progress page. If I could open all Wizard pages offset to the left or top, for example, it would mean both windows would be visible at the same time, without having to reposition them. Is this possible and, if so, how could it be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just offset the `WizardForm.Left` and `WizardForm.Top` as needed:

```pascal
procedure InitializeWizard();
begin
  WizardForm.Left := WizardForm.Left - ScaleX(320);
  WizardForm.Top := WizardForm.Top - ScaleY(160);
end;
```

Or maybe:

```pascal
procedure InitializeWizard();
begin
  WizardForm.Left := WizardForm.Left div 2;
  WizardForm.Top := WizardForm.Top div 2;
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

It's been a while since I've used INNO, but I believe you can do this with some custom code in the [CODE] section.  You'd have to create a overload to modify WizardForm..Left and WizardForm..Top as appropriate in InitializeWizard().

Check CodeDlg.iss and CodeClassess.iss in the Examples folder, and possibly the rest in there, for examples (sic) and details on how to properly set up the [CODE] section.

Useful docs:  http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=scriptclasses